# Extract only text in Hindi from a file containing both Hindi and English

Tags: python, file, unicode

I have a file containing lines like

```
 ted    1-1 1.0 politicians do not have permission to do what needs to be 
 done.  

 राजनीतिज्ञों के पास जो कार्य करना चाहिए, वह करने कि अनुमति नहीं है.
```

I have to write a program which reads the file line by line and gives the output in a file containing only the Hindi part. Here the first word indicates the source of the last two segments. Also, the last two sentences are translations of each other.
Basically, I am trying to create a parallel corpus out of this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by checking Unicode character.

```
import codecs,string
def detect_language(character):
    maxchar = max(character)
    if u'\u0900' <= maxchar <= u'\u097f':
        return 'hindi'

with codecs.open('letter.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    input = f.read()
    for i in input:
        isEng = detect_language(i)
        if isEng == "hindi":
            #Hindi Character
            #add this to another file
            print(i,end="\t")
            print(isEng)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Open two files—one for reading and the other for writing. Iterate over lines in your input file, using an if condition with a regex check to filter non-hindi lines, and write to the output file.

```
import re

hindi_lines = []
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f2:
   for line in f:
       if not (re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]', line) or line.strip()):
           f2.write(line)
```